# What does #{}-expansion in ANT mean?

Tags: java, ant

I'm having an ANT script with following line:

```
<property file="build" prefix="buildData"/>
<property name="buildNumber" value="#{buildData.buildNumber}"/>
```

What does the `#{buildData.buildNumber}` mean?

Comment: Is it really a `#` and not a `$`?

Comment: Definitely. I know '$' and '@', but not '#'.

Comment: Well, same here... Are you sure this is actually processed by ant and not some other tool?

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure anymore as it seems that no one knows '#' :) I don't have access to the server where this script runs successfully, but I guess there must be some additional magic there.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the # isn't a typo that should be a $ instead? If you use a $ instead of a # in the value, it will reference the value `buildData.buildNumber` from the referenced properties file.

Comment: I know '$' and '@', but it's really '#'.

Comment: And it does not work for me locally, but it's working on a server.

Comment: I really think this is a typo.

Look in your build.properties file. Is there a value in there for
buildData.buildNumber=?

Comment: I found a related line `<property file="build" prefix="buildData"/>`. Yes, seems like the `build` file would contain `buildNumber`. Still this makes no sense to me.

Comment: Try echoing ${buildNumber}.  If it echoes a value other than the literal string "#{buildData.buildNumber}", try commenting out that line and echo again.

Comment: It's actually `#{buildData.buildNumber}`. If I'm trying to set `buildNumber` in the `build` file, this does not work, as the `build` file is removed somewhere before `<property file="build" prefix="buildData"/>` is executed. So some strange magic is happening here on the server. I'll close this question, sorry for the noise.

Comment: Is it possible that the environment this came from is using [Flaka](https://code.google.com/p/flaka/)?  That's the only Ant related thing I know of that uses this kind of syntax.  If you really do have Flaka installed, see this for an explanation: http://workbench.haefelinger.it/flaka/download/manual/flaka-1.2.2.html#el

Answer (score 1):

Does it work actually? AFAIK it should be a `$` and not a `#`